# ASP.NET Forms Authentication without Redirect

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication, forms, redirect

I am using **ASP.Net's forms authentication**, but do not want the default behavior of redirecting to a login page when a restricted area is accessed. Instead I would like to invoke a javascript JQuery dialog for the login on the current page, preventing the content behind from loading.

**My only issue is that by default the forms authentication wants to redirect.**

Is there a **handler** that I can hook into, or some other option to **prevent the redirect**?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Dewfy:

Add the following to your web.config:

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <authenticationService enabled="true" />    
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

You can now call the authentication service from JavaScript like:

```
 Sys.Services.AuthenticationService.login("username",
    "password", false, null, null, loginCompleted, loginFailed, "");

 function loginCompleted()
 {
     var loginSuccessful = Sys.Services.AuthenticationService.get_isLoggedIn();
     if(loginSuccessful) /* do stuff */
 }

 function loginFailed(result, userContext, method)
 {
     alert('Exception ' + result.get_message());
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you deal with JQuery review possibility to use standard ASP.Net ajax oriented 
`Sys.Services.AuthenticationService`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with jQuery. But +1 for `Sys.Services.AuthenticationService`. That's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the [`LoginView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.aspx) control. This lets you set different templates for anonymous users and users that have logged in. It still uses ASP.NET authentication, so you can keep your current forms based authentication.